Handler should be static to prevent leaks and default constructor is deprecated confusion
I have a Handler in my MainActivity that receives messages from a Service.
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            String status = bundle.getString("status");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text)).setText(status_text);
    }
}
final Messenger mClientMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

It complains that my Handler class should be static or leaks may occur.  If I make it static it complains that findViewById is a non-static method and cannot be referenced from a static context.  It seems to me the Handler class to be almost useless if you can't use non-static methods.
Question 1:  How can I assure no leaks will occur with mClientMessenger?  Can I safely suppress the leak warning?
Edit: Question 1 answered here.
Question 2: Also, it complains the default constructor for android.os.Handler class is deprecated.  How can I satisfy this warning?

This question is similar to: What do I use now that Handler() is deprecated?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not defining the class in the same way as that question.  I'm not explicitly using a looper.  It is too confusing for me.  I don't understand how to port those solutions to my case.
